# jQuery: is there a reason not to always use live() for click and other functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I really like using .live() in jQuery for click() focus() blur() and other interaction events.

I do a lot of prototyping, so I find it gives me great flexibility if I want to dynamically add elements. For that reason, I find myself drawn to the idea of using it by default all the time. Is this a good idea, or is this bad performance?

Does using `.live('click',function(){})` slow things down in a way that `.click(function(){})` doesn't?

Comment: if you are not appending elements dynamically to the DOM or you dont want the click handler to be attached to dynamically added elements dont use `live` because it costs you in terms of performance.

Comment: You might probably go with event bubbling sometimes instead.

Comment: Delegate() is very similar to live() except that instead of bubbling all the way to the body, you can specify a parent container where the bubbling will stop. It's more performant and the syntax is very similar. http://api.jquery.com/delegate

Comment: check this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690370/live-vs-bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need your events to bubble up to the top of the DOM and you know the context in which your event will occur then [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is a much better choice in terms of performance.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204316/jquery-live-vs-delegate/4204349#4204349) stackoverflow post on why [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is better than [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in this regards.

Comment: Everyone gave useful answers here, but this one is the best. I'll be using delegate a lot more from now on.

Answer (score 1):

I think following answer will be suitable for the performance impact it does create [How does jQuery .live() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801070/how-does-jquery-live-work)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the performance, using the live is better in most cases. However live has several pitfalls, which are described in the documentation here http://api.jquery.com/live/#caveats.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that .live uses event bubbling.

In my experience, I've seen noticeable performance hit using .live in big document with a frequently triggered event like mouseover.

jQuery Doc:

> But as of jQuery 1.4, event bubbling can optionally stop at a DOM
>   element "context".

So, you can use that to minimize the performance effect.