# jquery click event handler for items within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you add a jquery click event handler for a bunch of links within a div? For example:

```
<div class="test">
<a href="test1.html">link 1</a>
<a href="test2.html">link 2</a>
<a href="test3.html">link 3</a>
</div>
```

I'd like to add a click event handler for each of the three links, so I can addClass('selected') to the link that was clicked on and removeClass('selected') from the rest.

I know I can do them one by one, but I was wondering what the cleanest way to do this is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
var classname = 'selected';

$('div.test').delegate('a', 'click', function ()
{
    $(this).addClass(classname).siblings().removeClass(classname);
});
```

Comment: Why delegate()?  He did not say he was going to add more "div.test a" to the DOM?

Comment: In general, it's better to bind fewer event handlers. Older versions of IE and mobile browsers appreciate it.

Comment: Is this any different than `$('div.test a').bind('click', function [etc]);` ?

Comment: @Matt - I see the "or in the future" as a big difference, but the "for all elements that match the selector" suggests (to me) that you wouldn't get fewer event handlers this way vs. 'div.test a'

Comment: @StephenP `.delegate()` works by binding a single event listener to the selected element(s). That's how the "in the future" part is implemented - it takes advantage of event bubbling. It is very similar to `.live()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801070/how-does-jquery-live-work

Answer (score 5):

The selector will return an array of elements that match.

```
$('div.test a')
```

will be the tree links.

```
$('div.test a').click(function() { });
```

Will bind to all three.

Answer (score 2):

Selectors work like CSS selectors, so this selects `a` tags inside tags with class `test`

```
$('.test a').click(function(){

    // select the object that was clicked on
    $(this)
        // add the selected class to it
        .addClass('selected')
        // remove the selected class from it's brothers and sisters
        .siblings().removeClass('selected')

    // stop link from loading and resetting page
    return false

})
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/HK6CE/

Answer (score 1):

I would write (with no extra markup):

> $('.test a').bind('click', function() {
>
> $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
>
> });

Siblings() gets all the others dom elements on the same level, so it'll get all the others "a" inside .test

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's `$('.test').each(function(){})`