# Wiring up click event using jQuery on() doesn't fire on injected HTML via Ajax call

Tags: jquery

I have a partial view which is returned via an Ajax call with a dataType of html - inside this html is an anchor tag with an id, which I am wiring up a click event using jQuery's `.on()` API and version 1.7.1 of the framework.

For brevity's sake, imagine the partial view is as follows:

```
<div id="container" class="modal-dialog">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <a id="thelink" href="#">
        <img src="<%:Url.Content("~/Path/To/Image.jpg")%>" /></a>
</div>
```

..and via a standard `$.ajax` POST to an MVC controller action which returns the above as a partial view result, which I intercept and spit into the modal dialog.

The event code that I'm attempting to hook up looks as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $("#thelink").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#jquery-ui-dialog-box").dialog("close");
    });
});
```

Now, if I switch the `on()` to `live()` - everything works as expected. With the code above though in IE8 (IE8 Standards mode) the event does not fire - breakpoints are not hit, the jQuery UI modal doesn't close as per the example above. With a `live()` call though, it all works as expected.

This is the first and only time I've ever seen a differential between the behaviour of on() and the deprecated or 'rolled up' event binding API (delegate, live, bind)

I have no issues with reverting to using `live()` or `delegate()` but would like to understand why this is occurring, if that is possible!

Regards
SB

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$(foo).live(type, handler)` is equivalent to `$(document).on(type, foo, handler)`, so try the following instead;

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", '#thelink', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#jquery-ui-dialog-box").dialog("close");
    });
});
```

The signature of `live()` is confusing; you're not actually binding a handler to the selected elements, but to the `document` element, which listens for an event to be fired on an element which matches the given selector ( [How does jQuery .live() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801070/how-does-jquery-live-work) ).

`$(foo).live(type, handler)` is equivalent to `$(document).delegate(foo, type, handler)`;

For future reference, `$(foo).delegate(selector, type, handler)` can be converted to `on()` just by swapping the first and second parameters; `on()` expects the event type *first*, then the (optional) selector.

Comment: +1 - perfect - I blindly assumed (wrongly) that the 'signature' of the event wire-up would be the same, but it isn't. Integrating your suggestion works for my actual code. Cheers.

Comment: @Matt If application has many screens and navigations, and we bind many click handler to $(document), the performance could be impacted. isn't it?

Comment: @Samba: Whilst correct, you're talking about many, *many*, ***many*** before you notice any performance degradation. Don't forget you can use `delegate()` or `on()` to attach to elements closer to the target element, rather than attaching to `document`.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for reply. But the problem with $(container).on approach is that - if the container is added to DOM dynamically by Ajax response, it doesn't work, so forced to use document.

Comment: @Matt It will be great help if you could comment on a approach, I was thinking to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382328/jquery-automatically-attach-or-register-event-handlers-to-user-actions-on-elem