# jQuery doesn't fire event on after-injected form

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm using jQuery 2.0.0 and I have a basic page with 2 links. If the user clicks on the links for each one a form is loaded via Ajax and injected to a container. Earlier it was possible to bind events to future elements with `live()` but nowadays it should be possible with `on()` I thought, but it doesn't fire the `submit` event, just if I inject the script after the form was injected it works. As browser I'm using Firefox 20.

Page:

```
<!-- Normal HTML5 head with jQuery loader //-->
<a href="./login">Login</a>
<!-- Normal HTML5 end //-->
```

Login (via Ajax):

```
<form id="login" action="./login">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

And finally my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        $('body').load($(this).attr('href'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    $('#login').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Some validation and as test if event is fired
        alert("Fired!");
    });

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wiring up click event using jQuery on() doesn't fire on injected HTML via Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756684/wiring-up-click-event-using-jquery-on-doesnt-fire-on-injected-html-via-ajax-c)

Comment: `-1` This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 2.0 now and there is no `live()` method anymore. So the answer to the topic you posted seems to be outdated.

Comment: The answer suggests `on` method actually.

Comment: Okay, but as I wrote above, `on` doesn't work. Could you recreate this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [opened a bug on jQuery](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13890) and it seems to be that everybody has to use event delegation like in [this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VPGpy/1/):

```
$('#inject').on('click', function(e) {
    $('body').html('<form id="login" action="./login"> \
                       <label for="username">Username:</label> \
                       <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /> \
                       <label for="password">Password:</label> \
                       <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /> \
                       <input type="submit" value="Login" /> \
                   </form>');
});

$('body').on('submit', '#login', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Some validation and as test if event is fired
    alert("Fired!");
});
```